# Why is $\frac{25}{2} \left(-2 + \pi -\tan^{-1}\frac{44}{117}\right)$ equivalent to $\frac{75}{2}\sin^{-1}\frac{4}{5}-25$?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, definite-integrals

I was following along a [MindYourDecisions problem on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cPNdvdYn05c)

[image: MindYourDecisions problem]

I flipped the image, split the problem in two sections, then feeling lazy I used Wolfram Alpha to do the calculus:

```
left circle
x^2 + (y-5)^2 = 5^2
y = 5 - sqrt(25 - x^2)

bottom circle
(x-5)^2 + y^2 = 5^2
y = sqrt(10 x - x^2)

big circle
x^2 + (y-10)^2 = 10^2
y = 10 - sqrt(100 - x^2)

Part 1: Left area
integrate left - big from 0 to 5
integrate (5 - sqrt(25 - x^2)) - (10 - sqrt(100 - x^2)) from 0 to 5
(25 (6 (-2 + Sqrt[3]) + Pi))/12

Part 2: Intersection
bottom = big
sqrt(10 x - x^2) = 10 - sqrt(100 - x^2)
x = 0, x = 8

Part 3: Right area
bottom - big
integrate bottom - big from 5 to 8
integrate (sqrt(10 x - x^2)) - (10 - sqrt(100 - x^2)) from 5 to 8
(25 (5 Pi - 6 (Sqrt[3] + ArcTan[44/117])))/12

Part 1 + Part 3
(25 (6 (-2 + Sqrt[3]) + Pi))/12 + (25 (5 Pi - 6 (Sqrt[3] + ArcTan[44/117])))/12
```

This simplified to:

```
25/2 (-2 + π - tan^(-1)(44/117))
```

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=25%2F2+%28-2+%2B+%CF%80+-+arctan%2844%2F117%29%29

Now, I checked the answer in the video:

```
37.5*arcsin(0.8)-25
```

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=37.5*arcsin%280.8%29-25

That surprised me, I assumed I did something wrong. But numerically, they seem to be identical: `9.7735706750604587160692173595910801521402790714590197858199`

How are these solutions connected? It doesn't "feel" right that `44/117` and `0.8` are connected.

Comment: there is a $(44, 117, 125)$  right triangle.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

(This space intentionally left blank.)

Comment: Very nice!$\quad$

Answer (score 2):

Let $\theta = \tan^{-1}\frac{44}{117}$ and $\phi =\sin^{-1}\frac{4}{5}$.  Then equating your two expressions reduces quickly to

$$\pi-\theta = 3\phi.$$

Take $\sin$ of both sides and apply difference of angles formula and triple angle formula:

$$\sin \theta = \sin 3\phi = 3\sin \phi -4\sin^3\phi.$$

Note that $(44,117,125)$ is a Pythagorean triple.  So $\sin \theta = 44/125$.   Also $\sin \phi = 4/5$ so the right side above is $3\left(4/5\right)-4\left(4/5\right)^3 = 44/124.$

So it's the triple angle formula for sine that makes the relationship.

Answer (score 2):

So, you want to know whether or not$$\require{cancel}\frac{25}2\left(-2+\pi-\arctan\left(\frac{44}{117}\right)\right)=\frac{75}2\arcsin\left(\frac45\right)-25.\label{a}\tag1$$We have\begin{align}\eqref{a}&\iff\cancel{-2}+\pi-\arctan\left(\frac{44}{117}\right)=3\arcsin\left(\frac45\right)\cancel{-2}\\&\iff3\arcsin\left(\frac45\right)+\arctan\left(\frac{44}{117}\right)=\pi.\end{align}Now, note that:

- $\displaystyle\sin\left(\arcsin\left(\frac45\right)\right)=\frac45$;
- $\displaystyle\cos\left(\arcsin\left(\frac45\right)\right)=\sqrt{1-\left(\frac45\right)^2}\text{(since }\arcsin\left(\frac45\right)\in\left(0,\frac\pi2\right)\text{)}=\frac35$.

Now, it follows from the formulas of the sine of the addition and of the cosine of the addition that$$\sin\left(3\arcsin\left(\frac45\right)\right)=\frac{44}{125}$$and that$$\cos\left(3\arcsin\left(\frac45\right)\right)=-\frac{117}{125}.$$

On the other hand, if $\displaystyle s=\sin\left(\arctan\left(\frac{44}{117}\right)\right)$ and $\displaystyle c=\cos\left(\arctan\left(\frac{44}{117}\right)\right)$, then $\displaystyle\frac sc=\frac{44}{117}$ and $c^2+s^2=1$; therefore, since $c,s>0$, $\displaystyle s=\frac{44}{125}$ and $\displaystyle c=\frac{117}{125}$. So\begin{align}\sin\left(3\arcsin\left(\frac45\right)+\arctan\left(\frac{44}{117}\right)\right)&=\frac{44\times117}{125^2}-\frac{44\times117}{125^2}\\&=0.\end{align}But$$0<3\arcsin\left(\frac45\right)+\arctan\left(\frac{44}{117}\right)<3\frac\pi2+\frac\pi2=2\pi$$and therefore$$3\arcsin\left(\frac45\right)+\arctan\left(\frac{44}{117}\right)=\pi$$indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Let $z=3+4i$ and $\theta=\arg z=\tan^{-1}(\tfrac{4}{3})$. We evaluate $3\theta$ in two ways.

On the one hand, $z^3=-117+44i$ so $$3\theta=\arg z^3 =\pi-\tan^{-1}(\tfrac{44}{117})$$where the extra $\pi$ occurs as $\Im (z^3)=-117<0$.

On the other hand, as $3^2+4^2=5^2$, $$\theta=\sin^{-1}(\tfrac{4}{5})$$ giving

$$3\sin^{-1}(\tfrac{4}{5})=\pi-\tan^{-1}(\tfrac{44}{117})$$

It is simple to rearrange this to get the desired identity.

$$37.5\sin^{-1}(\tfrac{4}{5})-25=\frac{25}{2}\left(-2+\pi-\tan^{-1}(\tfrac{44}{117})\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

In our case, $\arcsin\frac{4}{5}$ is the larger angle of a $(3, 4, 5)$ right triangle, which we can thus also write as $\arctan \frac{4}{3}$. Substituting and rearranging the desired equality gives that it is equivalent to the expression
$$\pi - \arctan \frac{44}{117} = 3 \arctan \frac{4}{3}$$
expressed just in terms of arctangents.

Suppose $a, b, c$ are the legs and hypotenuse, respectively, of a right triangle. In complex notation, the Pythagorean Theorem is
$$|a + bi|^2 = c^2 ,$$
and cubing $a + bi$ and $c$ gives that
$$|(a^3 - 3 a b^2) + i (3 a^2 b - b^3)|^2 = c^6 .$$
Comparing arguments gives $$\arg [(a^3 - 3 a b^2) + i (3 a^2 b - b^3)] = 3 \arg (a + b i)$$ for a suitable branch of the argument function, say the one taking values in $[0, 2 \pi)$. Indeed, assuming w.l.o.g. that $a < b$, we have $\arg (a + b i) \in \left(\frac{\pi}{4}, \frac{\pi}{2}\right)$, so the angle $3 \arg (a + b i)$ is in the second or third quadrant, where $\arg (x + y i) = \pi + \arctan \frac{y}{x}$. Thus,
$$3 \arctan \frac{b}{a} = \pi + \arctan \frac{3 a^2 b - b^3}{a^3 - 3 a b^2}.$$

Now, substituting $a = 3, b = 4$ into our above formula gives
$$3 \arctan \frac{4}{3} = \pi + \arctan \left(- \frac{44}{117}\right) = \pi - \arctan \frac{44}{117}$$
as desired.

**Remark** You can use the same principle for other powers of $a + bi$ (and for that matter, other Pythagorean primitive triples). For example, taking the fourth power of $a + bi$ gives that for $(a, b)$ with argument $< \frac{\pi}{8}$ we have
$$4 \arctan \frac{b}{a} = \arctan \frac{4 a b(a^2 - b^2)}{a^4 - 6 a^2 b^2 + b^4},$$ and fixing $a = 5, b = 1$ gives
$$4 \arctan \frac{1}{5} = \arctan \frac{120}{119},$$
which is tantalizingly close to $\arctan 1 = \frac{\pi}{4}$, motivating computing the difference of these angles. Taking $p = \frac{120}{119}$ and $q = 1$ in the arctangent difference formula,
$$\arctan p - \arctan q = \arctan \frac{p - q}{1 + pq}$$ gives
a difference of $$\arctan \frac{\frac{120}{119} - 1}{1 + \frac{120}{119} \cdot 1} = \arctan \frac{1}{239} \approx \frac{1}{239},$$
recovering [Machin's famous formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machin-like_formula) useful for approximating $\pi$ numerically:
$$4 \arctan \frac{1}{5} - \arctan \frac{1}{239} = \frac{\pi}{4} .$$